# Make Python aritmetic operations

Tags: python, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/python-limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

If I make this: 12.45-12

in Python the answer I get is: 0.44999999999999929

I do I do it to make it: 0.45?

BTW I did remember to do: 12.45-12.0
But no result.

Comment: Duplicate.  Please SEARCH for Floating-Point in Python.  PLease.  Are you talking about currency?  Money?  Use `decimal`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a result of the fact that many decimals cannot be exactly represented in binary.

For example, 0.25 can: it's `0.01` (0*1, 0*1/2, 1*1/4). 0.1 can't (`0.0001100110011...`), just like you can't write 1/3 as a complete decimal (`0.3333333333...`).

If you do

```
print(12.45-12)
```

you get

```
0.45
```

because `print` only displays the first significant digits.

See the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues) for an excellent summary.

If you do care about decimal values being exact (for example to avoid a Superman III scenario in a financial institution), look at the [Decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly OK, but you need to google (and search around on StackOverflow) for "IEEE 754".

EDIT: Take a look e.g. here: [Inaccurate Logarithm in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931995/inaccurate-logarithm-in-python) or here: [Another floating point question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048865/another-floating-point-question)

Answer (score 2):

Also in Python 2.4 up, check out the [decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module if you need more accuracy.